# escaping html tags in p:layoutUnit

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

I want to generate site content in layoutUnit (it can contains line breaks, paragraphs, headers and so on). How to do this? Merging text and HTML tags do not works for me. Maybe generating tags is a bad idea? What is proper approach for that case?

I have:

```
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        #{siteContent.code}
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

My ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class SiteContent
{
  private String _code;

  public SiteContent()
  {
    _code = "String1<br>String2";
  }

  public String getCode()
  {
    return _code;
  }

}
```

On my site instead new line I have "String1
String2" (String<br>String2 in html code).

Comment: So you are saying this works if you don't use a layout in a page but e.g. plain div?

Comment: I commented all code between <h:body><h:body> and I put beetween these tags: #{siteContent.code} and <div>#{siteContent.code}</div>. Result is the same. I have on my site "<br>" instead of new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that

```
<h:outputText value="#{siteContent.code}" escape="false" />
```

generate code without escaping.